# animation triggered for incorrect class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I have two classes, `class1` and `class2`. I've tied `class2` to an animation with `.class2-add`. However in the following example, toggling either class triggers the animation. What gives?

http://plnkr.co/edit/V1bf0waCnUWCt58F3Y63

I don't want the animation to trigger when I toggle `class1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

> When the expression changes, the previously added classes are removed and only then the new classes are added.

That means classes are removed and re-added back to your directive which is why it re-trigger your `.class2-add`

Depending on your actual use cases, there is no straight fix that I know of.

A bit of remedy to my knowledge is using CSS:

```
.class1-add.class2-add {
  -webkit-transition:none;
  -moz-transition:none;
  -o-transition:none;
  transition:none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

to cancel out the animation when they are both exist at the same time.

Or

```
ng-class="{class1: class1, class2: class2 && !class1}"
```

Both method however will still trigger your `.class2-add` when your `.class1` is removed and `.class2` is currently active (TRUE).

So to sum up, `-add` will be re-triggered when `ng-class` receive the changes.

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/bFhKyNZBi5uEG0cyCAc7?p=preview